# Can a covergent series contain undefined points.

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is really just about definitions. If I have, for example $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{k}}{k}$ this will converge for $|x| < 1$

However if I have $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{k}}{k}$ the series is undefined for $k = 0$

Can this series be said to be convergent, even though it contains an undefined point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum is clearly not defined in $\mathbb{R}$, though it is defined (and converges to $\infty$) in $\mathbb{R}\cup{\{\infty\}}$ (with open sets of the form $U\cup\{\infty\}$ where $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$) assuming that $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus{\{0\}}$ and  the convention $\frac{x}{0}=\infty$ is used.

Comment: Is that a one-point compactification of $\mathbb R$? Otherwise how do you choose between $+\infty$ and $-\infty$?

Comment: @par Is the convention $\frac{x}{0}=\infty$ something generally used for series, or are you saying we could define that convention to give an answer for this particular equation?

Comment: @mathguy: you are correct. Changing notation.

Comment: @nHaskins: it is used sometimes, but if you are just learning analysis, I would stick to $\mathbb{R}$ and consider your series as not well-defined.